# Which jdbc driver do I need for netbeans 11 to work with mysql 8.0?

Tags: netbeans, driver

I'm trying to set up a connection to mysql server to netbeans but are having issues with mysql. p.s. Can someone give me a download link for the .jarfile for the jdbc driver?

I tried installing several drivers but to no avail. I recently unistalled mysql because the server was failing to initiliase in workbench too.

```
public class conn 
{
     Connection c;
     Statement s;
     public conn()
     {
         try
         {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             c =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
             //miniproject");     
             s =c.createStatement();
         } 
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println(e);
         }
     }
}
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

the download link for the jarfile for the jdbc driver is :

```
     https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
```

choose : Platform independent 
         then download the latest Connector/j jar file

or click archive to download earlier version.
the link for archives is : https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/